# Item selections needs two clicks on IOS in vue js multiselect

Tags: ios, vue.js, multi-select

I Used `multiselect` dropdown in `Vue.js` its working fine on all devices and web. In iOS we need to tap two times to select an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this following `code` in your **CSS file** to overwrite *multiselect* default `css`, as these **classes** are conflicting in **iOS** **device**:

```
.multiselect__option--highlight:after{
  display: none
}
.multiselect__option--selected:after{
  display: none
}
.multiselect__option--selected.multiselect__option--highlight:after{
  display: none
}
```